Getting the Updated Width & Height of a ViewGroup
I have a .NET for Android app containing a GridLayout for which I need the Width/Height. Right now both of these return 0, which is not surprising, since I am attempting to access them in OnResume. The size of this GridLayout does not change, but I need to know the Width/Height in order to calculate the layout of some of it's child Views. I have tried using methods such as Invalidate(), RequestLayout() & ForceLayout(), but they did not seem to help. How can I force the Width/Height to be updated, or when/where should I put the code that requires the Width/Height? Here is a screenshot of what I currently get:

The area below the tabs (the area containing the people & numbers) is a GridLayout, for which I need to know the Height. I need this value so that I can calculate the positions for the numbers. Because the size of the tabs does not change, the only time this need recalculated is when the orientation changes. Any ideas? Thanks!

It would be more helpful to know why you want to know the size in onResume and what behaviour you want to achieve with GridLayout. Showing your code would help.

This question is similar to: measuring a view before rendering it and Determining the size of an Android view at runtime. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You won't be able to access them in onResume, because the UI isn't drawn yet.  As the UI isn't drawn, the UI elements haven't figure out the size they should be yet.
You're kind of doing things wrong.  If you want a layout to scale with the size of its children, you make it's width and/or height WRAP_CONTENT and let the children size themselves.  The only time you might size the parent layout off of the child like that is when making a custom layout of your own, which would require a custom onMeasure and onLayout.  In fact trying to size the parent based on the child in any other way would likely infinitely loop them as changing the parent will cause a recalculation of the size of the child.  Especially with gridlayout, which has a lot of built in functionality to set sizes of rows/columns based on child size.  Without more info of what you're trying to do we can't really give more specific advice, but you're probably approaching it wrong.

There is no evidence that this is wrong, unusual yes.

@Andrew If you understand how views and layout on Android work at all, it's pretty obvious that it's wrong.  If you really need to customize the parent to the size of the child, you're talking about making a custom layout that does something other than what GridLayout does.  Most likely he doesn't need to do any of that and needs to describe what he actually wants so we can tell him how to do it.  But the method for calculating the height of a parent from its child is the measure pass, not trying to do an end run around it (which would likely cause infinite remeasures)

I understand perfectly how views, layout and Layout manager work and seen a number of examples where even Google themselves call measure outside the normal layout flow and it's pretty obvious there are limited use cases where this is required. It's also pretty obvious that it's designed to be called multiple times without a lasting effect.
